# pwquality.conf difok clarification

Tags: password

in `/etc/security/pwquality.conf` there is `difok`

*Number of characters in the new password that must not be present in the old password.*

Is that regardless of character position?

Such that if my minimum 12 character password is

`abcdefghijkl`

that a password change to `123abcdefghi` would be prevented based on a *difok=8* ?

Comment: The way it's phrased in the `man` page indicates it considers characters, not their position. Should be easy enough to test (my system lacks `pwquality.conf` so I can't do this).